# What is '$$' in the bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm beginner at bash shell programming. Can you tell me about '$$' symbols in the bash shell?

If I try the following

```
#> echo $$
```

it prints

```
#>18756
```

Can you tell me what this symbol is used for and when?

Comment: What has become of the good old tradition of reading the fine manual for your shell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's the process id of the bash process itself.

You might use it to track your process over its life - use [`ps -p`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) to see if it's still running, send it a signal using `kill` (to pause the process for example), change its priority with `renice`, and so on.

Process ids are often written to log files, especially when multiple instances of a script run at once, to help track performance or diagnose problems.

Here's [the bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) outlining special parameters.

[`BASHPID`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables), mentioned by ghostdog74, was added at version 4.0.  Here's an example from Mendel Cooper's *[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf)* that shows the difference between `$$` and `$BASHPID`:

```
#!/bin/bash4

echo "\$\$ outside of subshell = $$" # 9602
echo "\$BASH_SUBSHELL outside of subshell = $BASH_SUBSHELL" # 0
echo "\$BASHPID outside of subshell = $BASHPID" # 9602
echo

( echo "\$\$ inside of subshell = $$" # 9602
echo "\$BASH_SUBSHELL inside of subshell = $BASH_SUBSHELL" # 1
echo "\$BASHPID inside of subshell = $BASHPID" ) # 9603
# Note that $$ returns PID of parent process.
```

Comment: Or you could link directly to the official Bash documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Variables

Answer (score 1):

if you have bash, a relatively close equivalent is the BASHPID variable. See man bash

```
  BASHPID
      Expands  to  the  process  id of the current bash process.  This differs from $$ under certain circumstances, such as subshells
      that do not require bash to be re-initialized.
```